# Add and update function is not working in SharePoint online list using SPfx PnP.js coding

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

Using the below SPFx PnP.js code I am doing the CRUD operation in SharePoint online list:

```
private _getListData(): Promise<ISPList[]> {
 return pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("EmployeeList").items.get().then((response) => {

    return response;
  });

}

 private getListData(): void {

    this._getListData()
      .then((response) => {
        this._renderList(response);
      });
}

AddItem()
{  

     pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('EmployeeList').items.add({    
     EmployeeName : document.getElementById('EmployeeName')["value"],
     Experience : document.getElementById('Experience')["value"],
     Location:document.getElementById('Location')["value"]
    });
     alert("Record with Employee Name : "+ document.getElementById('EmployeeName')["value"] + " Added !");

}

UpdateItem()
{  

    var id = document.getElementById('EmployeeId')["value"];
    pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("EmployeeList").items.getById(id).update({
     EmployeeName : document.getElementById('EmployeeName')["value"],
     Experience : document.getElementById('Experience')["value"],
     Location:document.getElementById('Location')["value"]
  });
 alert("Record with Employee Name : "+ document.getElementById('EmployeeName')["value"] + " Updated !");
}

DeleteItem()
{  
     pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("EmployeeList").items.getById(document.getElementById('EmployeeId')["value"]).delete();
     alert("Record with Employee ID : "+ document.getElementById('EmployeeId')["value"] + " Deleted !");
}
```

In the above code **AddItem()** and **UpdateItem()** are not working but reading list items and deleting list item are working. I mean I am not able to **add new record** to the list and **update** also not getting any errors, getting the successful alert message but it is not adding or updating the items. Any issue with the AddItem() and updateItem() function code....any help will be much appreciated.

**Updated**

I am not getting any error though it add and update function is not working, by the way I am global administrator.

While clicking on the add button getting the successful alert message but it is not adding, screenshot attached:

[image]

**Complete code reference:**

```
 import pnp from 'sp-pnp-js';
//import { default as pnp, ItemAddResult } from "sp-pnp-js";
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  BaseClientSideWebPart,
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';

import styles from './PnPspCrud.module.scss';
import * as strings from 'pnPspCrudStrings';
import { IPnPspCrudWebPartProps } from './IPnPspCrudWebPartProps';

        export interface ISPList {
      ID: string;
      EmployeeName: string;
      Experience: string;
      Location: string;
    } 

export default class PnPspCrudWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IPnPspCrudWebPartProps> {


private AddEventListeners() : void{
 document.getElementById('AddItem').addEventListener('click',()=>this.AddItem());
 document.getElementById('UpdateItem').addEventListener('click',()=>this.UpdateItem());
 document.getElementById('DeleteItem').addEventListener('click',()=>this.DeleteItem());
}

 private _getListData(): Promise<ISPList[]> {
 return pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("EmployeeList").items.get().then((response) => {

    return response;
  });

}

 private getListData(): void {

    this._getListData()
      .then((response) => {
        this._renderList(response);
      });
}

private _renderList(items: ISPList[]): void {
  let html: string = '<table class="TFtable" border=1 width=100% style="border-collapse: collapse;">';
  html += `<th>EmployeeId</th><th>EmployeeName</th><th>Experience</th><th>Location</th>`;
  items.forEach((item: ISPList) => {
    html += `
         <tr>
        <td>${item.ID}</td>
        <td>${item.EmployeeName}</td>
        <td>${item.Experience}</td>
        <td>${item.Location}</td>
        </tr>
        `; 
  });
  html += `</table>`;
  const listContainer: Element = this.domElement.querySelector('#spGetListItems');
  listContainer.innerHTML = html;
}



  public render(): void {
    this.domElement.innerHTML = `

      <div class="parentContainer" style="background-color: lightgrey">
<div class="ms-Grid-row ms-bgColor-themeDark ms-fontColor-white ${styles.row}">
   <div class="ms-Grid-col ms-u-lg10 ms-u-xl8 ms-u-xlPush2 ms-u-lgPush1">
      <span class="ms-font-xl ms-fontColor-white" style="font-size:28px">Welcome to SharePoint Framework Development using PnP JS Library</span>
      <p class="ms-font-l ms-fontColor-white" style="text-align: left">Demo : SharePoint List CRUD using PnP JS and SPFx</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="ms-Grid-row ms-bgColor-themeDark ms-fontColor-white ${styles.row}">
   <div style="background-color:Black;color:white;text-align: center;font-weight: bold;font-size:18px;">Employee Details</div>

</div>
<div style="background-color: lightgrey" >
   <form >
      <br>
      <div data-role="header">
         <h3>Add SharePoint List Items</h3>
      </div>
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
         <div >
            <input id="EmployeeName"  placeholder="EmployeeName"    />
            <input id="Experience"  placeholder="Experience"  />
            <input id="Location"  placeholder="Location"    />
         </div>
         <div></br></div>
         <div >
            <button id="AddItem"  type="submit" >Add</button>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div data-role="header">
         <h3>Update/Delete SharePoint List Items</h3>
      </div>
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
         <div >
            <input id="EmployeeId"   placeholder="EmployeeId"  />
         </div>
         <div></br></div>
         <div >
            <button id="UpdateItem" type="submit" >Update</button>
            <button id="DeleteItem"  type="submit" >Delete</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
<br>
<div style="background-color: lightgrey" id="spGetListItems" />
</div>

   `;
this.getListData();
this.AddEventListeners();
  }


AddItem()
{  

     pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('EmployeeList').items.add({    
     EmployeeName : document.getElementById('EmployeeName')["value"],
     Experience : document.getElementById('Experience')["value"],
     Location:document.getElementById('Location')["value"]
    });
     alert("Record with Employee Name : "+ document.getElementById('EmployeeName')["value"] + " Added !");

}
/* 
AddItem()
{  

  pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('EmployeeList').items.add({    
    EmployeeName : document.getElementById('EmployeeName')["value"],
    Experience : document.getElementById('Experience')["value"],
    Location:document.getElementById('Location')["value"]
   })
.then(addResponse => {
    alert("Record with Employee Name : "+ document.getElementById('EmployeeName')["value"] + " Added !");
})
.catch(addError => alert("An error has occurred:" + JSON.stringify(addError)));

}
*/

/*
private AddItem():void
{
     pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("EmployeeList").items.add({
      EmployeeName : document.getElementById('EmployeeName')["value"],
      Experience : document.getElementById('Experience')["value"],
      Location: document.getElementById('Location')["value"]
  })
  .then((iar: ItemAddResult) => {
      console.log(iar);
  })
  .catch((error:any) => {
      console.log("Error: ", error);
  });

}
*/


UpdateItem()
{  

    var id = document.getElementById('EmployeeId')["value"];
    pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("EmployeeList").items.getById(id).update({
     EmployeeName : document.getElementById('EmployeeName')["value"],
     Experience : document.getElementById('Experience')["value"],
     Location:document.getElementById('Location')["value"]
  });
 alert("Record with Employee Name : "+ document.getElementById('EmployeeName')["value"] + " Updated !");
}

DeleteItem()
{  
     pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("EmployeeList").items.getById(document.getElementById('EmployeeId')["value"]).delete();
     alert("Record with Employee ID : "+ document.getElementById('EmployeeId')["value"] + " Deleted !");
}

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: strings.DescriptionFieldLabel
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Note:

I am referring this link where complete code is available.

https://www.sharepoint-journey.com/SharePoint-Framework-Development-Create-List-CRUD-WebPart-PnPJS.html

Answer (score 0):

Of course you get the alert function to call, because the add/update/delete functions from pnp/sp are asynchronous! you can try that:

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('EmployeeList').items.add({    
     EmployeeName : document.getElementById('EmployeeName')["value"],
     Experience : document.getElementById('Experience')["value"],
     Location:document.getElementById('Location')["value"]
    })
.then(addResponse => {
     alert("Record with Employee Name : "+ document.getElementById('EmployeeName')["value"] + " Added !");
})
.catch(addError => alert("An error has occurred:" + JSON.stringify(addError)));
```

I hope this helps, maybe if you get an error here you can update your post to dig deeper into the problem!

Greetings

Comment: @J. Benda: Added the complete code with screenshot - by the way I have tried with your code but it didn't work.

Comment: open in chorme network console (f12 and go to network). it may give u the error which is coming exactly. site url is not set kind. I will try ur code and let u know. try below.

Answer (score 0):

code has no issue. Best practice should be as mentioend @j.Benda. It seems permission issue.

Comment: I am global administrator and site owner to that site, so I think this is not a permission issue, by the way I am able to read and delete the list item...so if this is a permission issue this also would have not been worked.

Answer (score 0):

open in chorme network console (f12 and go to network). it may give u the error which is coming exactly. site url is not set kind. I will try ur code and let u know. try below. 
import { default as pnp, ItemAddResult, Web } from "sp-pnp-js";

```
on button events set web url.
onclickevnet(){
 var NewISiteUrl = this.props.siteurl;
    var NewSiteUrl = NewISiteUrl.replace("/SitePages", "");
    console.log(NewSiteUrl);
    let webx = new Web(NewSiteUrl)


webx.lists.getByTitle('EmployeeList').items.add({    
 EmployeeName : document.getElementById('EmployeeName')["value"],
 Experience : document.getElementById('Experience')["value"],
 Location:document.getElementById('Location')["value"]
})
.then(addResponse => {
     //error
})
.catch(addError => alert("An error has occurred:" + JSON.stringify(addError)));
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try that - by the way I am referring this link where complete code is available.
https://www.sharepoint-journey.com/SharePoint-Framework-Development-Create-List-CRUD-WebPart-PnPJS.html